# tensorflow 2.0, model.fit() : Your input ran out of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am absolutely new to TensorFlow and Keras, and I am trying to make my way around trying out some code that I am finding online.

In particular I am using the fashion-MNIST - consisting of 60000 examples and  test set of 10000 examples. Each of them is a 28x28 grayscale image.

I am following this tutorial "https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-first-neural-network-in-tensorflow-2-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-i-e1e2f1dfe7a0", and I have no problem until the definition of

```
history = model.fit(
train_dataset.repeat(), 
epochs=10, 
steps_per_epoch=500,
validation_data=val_dataset.repeat(), 
validation_steps=2)
```

As long as I understood, I need to use *train_dataset.repeat()* as input dataset because otherwise I won't have enough training example using those values for the hyperparameters (epochs, steps_per_epochs).

My question is: how can I avoid to have to use *.repeat()*? 
How do I need to change the hyperparameters?

I am coping the code here, for simplicity:

```
def preprocess(x,y):

    x = tf.cast(x,tf.float32) / 255.0
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    return x,y 

def create_dataset(xs, ys, n_classes=10):

    ys = tf.one_hot(ys, depth=n_classes)

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xs, ys)).map(preprocess).shuffle(len(ys)).batch(128)


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss =tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True), metrics =['accuracy'])

history1 = model.fit(train_dataset.repeat(), 
                    epochs=10, 
                    steps_per_epoch=500,
                    validation_data=val_dataset.repeat(), 
                    validation_steps=2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use .repeat() you need to have your model passing thought your entire data only one time per epoch.

In order to do that you need to calculate how many steps it will take for your model to pass throught the entire dataset, the calcul is easy :

```
steps_per_epoch = len(train_dataset) // batch_size
```

So with a train_dataset of 60 000 sample and a batch_size of 128, you need to have 468 steps per epoch.

By setting this parameter like that you make sure that you do not exceed the size of your dataset.

Comment: I tried! 
I run : 
''' 
history1 = model.fit(train_dataset, 
                    epochs=10, 
                    steps_per_epoch=468,
                    validation_data=val_dataset, 
                    validation_steps=2)
'''

But it runs for 1 epoch, and as soon as it starts the 2nd it gives me the error: 
*WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 4680 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.*

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and here is what I found.
Documentation of *tf.keras.Model.fit*:  "If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted."

In other words, we **don't** need to specify 'steps_per_epoch' if we use the tf.data.dataset as the training data, and tf will figure out how many steps are there. Meanwhile, tf will automatically repeat the dataset when the next epoch begins, so you can specify any 'epoch'.

When passing an infinitely repeating dataset (e.g. dataset.repeat()), you must specify the steps_per_epoch argument.

Comment: Note that during the first epoch, the total number of step will be marked as "unknown" and will only be made clear from the second epoch onward.